# cordova run ios - emulator opens but app does not install - error the operation couldn’t be completed. Application "myApp" is unknown to FrontBoard

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ios-simulator

I'm writing an app with Ionic v1, AngularJS 1.5 and Cordova cli v8.
Last week I updated my Mac OS (mac os Catalina 10.15.5) and now I'm having trouble launching app onto my ios emulators.

This is how I try to run my app: `cordova run ios --emulator`

```
cordova requirements ios

Requirements check results for android:

Java JDK: installed 1.8.0

Android SDK: installed true

Android target: installed android-28,android-26,android-19

Gradle: installed /usr/local/Cellar/gradle/6.2.1/bin/gradle



Requirements check results for ios:

Apple macOS: installed darwin

Xcode: installed 11.5

ios-deploy: installed 1.10.0

CocoaPods: installed 1.9.0


ionic info

[WARN] Bad integration name: gulp



Ionic:



   Ionic CLI         : 5.4.16 (/Users/aubrey/node_modules/ionic)

   Ionic Framework   : ionic1 1.3.5

   @ionic/v1-toolkit : 1.0.22



Cordova:



   Cordova CLI       : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)

   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0, ios 5.1.0

   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0, (and 17 other plugins)



Utility:



   cordova-res : 0.15.1

   native-run  : 1.0.0



System:



   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/usr/local/share/android-sdk)

   ios-deploy        : 1.10.0

   ios-sim           : 8.0.2

   NodeJS            : v10.19.0 (/usr/local/Cellar/node@10/10.19.0/bin/node)

   npm               : 6.13.4

   OS                : macOS Catalina


   Xcode             : Xcode 11.5 Build version 11E608c


cordova plugins list

cordova-android-support-gradle-release 3.0.1 "cordova-android-support-gradle-release"

cordova-plugin-camera 4.1.0 "Camera"

cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat"

cordova-plugin-customurlscheme 5.0.1 "Custom URL scheme"

cordova-plugin-device 2.0.3 "Device"

cordova-plugin-file 6.0.2 "File"

cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.7.1 "File Transfer"

cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.2 "Geolocation"

cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 4.0.0 "InAppBrowser"

cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"

cordova-plugin-network-information 2.0.2 "Network Information"

cordova-plugin-safariviewcontroller 1.6.0 "SafariViewController"

cordova-plugin-save-image 0.3.0 "SaveImage"

cordova-plugin-settings-hook 0.2.7 "Cordova Settings Hooks"

cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.4 "Splashscreen"

cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.3 "StatusBar"

cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.4 "Whitelist"

cordova.plugins.diagnostic 4.0.12 "Diagnostic"


ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
```

This is the error that I'm getting:

```
** BUILD SUCCEEDED **



Deploying to simulator

No target specified for emulator. Deploying to "iPhone-SE--2nd-generation-, 13.5" simulator.

Running command: /Users/aubrey/Documents/Repos/selfserviceapp/node_modules/ios-sim/bin/ios-sim launch /Users/aubrey/Documents/Repos/selfserviceapp/platforms/ios/build/emulator/Self Service.app --devicetypeid com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-SE--2nd-generation-, 13.5 --log /Users/aubrey/Documents/Repos/selfserviceapp/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log --exit

[ios-sim] device.name: iPhone SE (2nd generation)

[ios-sim] device.runtime: iOS 13.5

device.id: 6FCCD0AD-2E43-489A-B623-4D9AAA667637

[ios-sim] Simulator already running.

[ios-sim] An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):

Failed to install the requested application

An application bundle was not found at the provided path.


Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.



[ios-sim] An error was encountered processing the command (domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain, code=1):

The request to open "com.softworks.selfservice.app" failed.

The request was denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace) for reason: NotFound ("Application "com.softworks.selfservice.app" is unknown to FrontBoard").

Underlying error (domain=FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain, code=4):

[ios-sim] The operation couldn’t be completed. Application "com.softworks.selfservice.app" is unknown to FrontBoard.

    Application "com.softworks.selfservice.app" is unknown to FrontBoard.

com.softworks.selfservice.app: -1

[ios-sim] logPath: /Users/aubrey/Documents/Repos/selfserviceapp/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log

Simulator successfully started via `ios-sim`.
```

I tried this on a brand new project by `cordova create hello` and it does work for this brand new app but not for my project.

Edit correction: I created a fresh project with the Cordova 8.1.2 cli and tried to run it in the emulator and I got the same result.

**What I have tried:**

deleted node_modules, bower_components, plugins folders

tried Cordova platform rm ios & Cordova platform add ios